# Defining Complex Menu

Tags: php, user-interface, menu, atk4

How can I make a menu like this

```
          AOption1 | BOption2 | COption3  <-- This is the basic menu of atk4
```

But If I make click over "Option1" I'd like a menu like this

ASubOption1
   option1
   option2
   option3

ASubOption2
   option1
   option2
   option3

And the same if I make click over "BOption2"

Maybe tabs ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu included in Agile Toolkit is really simple one. What you can do is define a place for your sub-menu in the shared template and place the following code on your page:

```
$this->api->add('SubMenu',null,'SubmenuSpot');
```

then inside lib/SubMenu.php

```
class SubMenu extends Menu {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addMenuItem('suboption1');
        $this->addMenuItem('suboption2');
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can define the menu using CSS and use Menu_Light class to trigger highlight a current menu option:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Menu/Light.php

Comment: Romans, just a question, I have added a <?SubMenu?> in my shared.html and the code you wrote. When I try to load the page it gives me a "fatal: Cannot append to tag SubmenuSpot" but if I use null instead SubmenuSpot "this->api->add('subMenu',null,null)" I see the menu but under "content" and not where I want. I've tried adding a tag SubmenuSpot but with no luck. What i'm doing wrong ?. Thanks

Comment: Obviously you need to use "SubMenu" :)